# PHP cannot access object in array

Tags: php, arrays, object

in my application i get returned an array of objects and i am trying to access to access the object inside the array like this `$array[0]->name` but it doesn't work for some reason ,

i tried to access it like this - `$var = $array[0]; $var->name` and it shows me this error > `Trying to get property of non-object`

whats going on here ? why i cant access the object ?  and how can i access it ? 
also , would be better if i just got a multidimensional array instead array of objects?

var_dump://

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "нямам си и идея"
    ["description"]=>
    string(19) "емиииии....."
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "823"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "bg"
    ["category"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(7) "shalala"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "no tyore idea what "
    ["description"]=>
    string(22) "are you talking to me "
    ["price"]=>
    string(3) "823"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
    ["category"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(7) "shalala"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

vardump of $array[0]

```
object(stdClass)#16 (9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(27) "нямам си и идея"
  ["description"]=>
  string(19) "емиииии....."
  ["price"]=>
  string(3) "823"
  ["lang"]=>
  string(2) "bg"
  ["category"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(7) "shalala"
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["sid"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

[resolved] = the framework was pointing me at the wrong line of code the error was 10 lines down the code and i didnt see it :(

Comment: The error message says `$array[0]` isn't an object. Use `var_dump()` on it to see what's inside.

Comment: Can you paste the context of the code? It looks like there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Grodon , thats the output of the $array , in a sec iil add the $array[0]

Comment: Weird. $array[0]->name should work in this case. Use a debugger like Xdebug or Zend_Debugger to step throug the code to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What does is_object($array[0]) result in?

Comment: What happens when you run this code: `$a = new StdClass; $a->name = 'foo'; $array = array($a); echo $array[0]->name;`

Comment: it echoes "foo" weirdest thing when var_dumped $var->name gives propper value o.O

Answer (score 1):

The issue is somewhere else.

The `$array[0]` is NOT an object that's why it's saying `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Comment: that doesnt solve the issue and therefor should have been a comment

Comment: @Gordon, OK will remember next time.